# Checking for function signature

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a service locator project and I'm expecting functions to be passed in that require a single parameter.

Here's a snippet:

```js
"use strict";

/** Declaration types */
type ServiceDeclaration = Function|Object;

export default class Pimple {

    /**
     * @type {{}}
     * @private
     */
    _definitions: {[key: string]: ServiceDeclaration} = {};

    /**
     * Get a service instance
     * @param {string} name
     * @return {*}
     */
    get(name: string): any {
        if (this._definitions[name] instanceof Function) {
            return this._definitions[name](this);
        }
        return this._definitions[name];
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile this I get the following error:

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'ServiceDeclaration' has no compatible call signatures.
```

I tried creating a new type:

```
type ServiceFunction = (container: Pimple) => any;
```

And tried changing `instanceof Function` to `instanceof ServiceFunction` but then I get the following error:

```
error TS2693: 'ServiceFunction' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

I've looked around but haven't been able to find any examples of checking if a passed in function matches a specified signature.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a variable and let TypeScript infer its type:

```
    get(name: string): any {
        let f = this._definitions[name]; // here, 'f' is of type Function|Object
        if (f instanceof Function)
            return f(this);              // here, 'f' is of type Function
        return f;                        // here, 'f' is of type Object
    }
```

As an alternative, it is possible to wrap the condition in an explicit [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types):

```
function isFunction(f): f is Function {
    return f instanceof Function;
}
```

A small notice: The type `Object | Function` is not elegant. You may consider to use a better [function type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) and / or a better [object type](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/24/typescript-2-2-the-object-type).

Comment: Thanks. I tested a couple variations and found that the key part was assigning `let f = this._definitions[name];` first and then checking and using the local variable. I didn't need an external function, I was able to do `if (f instanceof Function) { return f; }`

Comment: f(this)...love it

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simpler solution than that of Paleo. Instead of using `instanceof Function`, you can use `typeof f === 'function'`. Click [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Input%20%3D%20object%20%7C%20Function%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20a(input%3A%20Input)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20input%20%3D%3D%3D%20'function')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20input%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20input%20is%20treated%20as%20a%20function%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20input%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20input%20is%20treated%20as%20an%20object.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D) for an example I've created on the TypeScript playground. If you mouse over the `input` variable in the two `if` branches, you'll see the result that you want.